# Consequences of changing the domain name with Janrain

Tags: migration, single-sign-on, janrain

On a website, I'm using Janrain to allow user to login/sign in. Due to a rebrand, the domain name will change to another one.

What will the consequences be ? Will my user need to sign in again ? Will they need to authorize the app again ? Are there stuff I need to tell Janrain about ?

As you can see I'm pretty new on Janrain. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things to consider when rebranding a site that uses Janrain Engage's auth widget:

1. SSL certs
2. Custom domain setup (cross-domain receiver page branding)

If you don't use either of the above (Pro/Enterprise level), then it's really easy and seamless.

Users that have previously authorized with social providers *should* remain unaffected, depending on your website's framework.  Feel free to post a discussion in our [Self-Help Forum](https://support.janrain.com/forums)

Comment: so far, I found out about the point 2. I already knew about ssl certs, as it's (almost) independant from Janrain. Ty for your support :)